# How to run Word macro (replace text) from Powershell?

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I am looking for a way to replace text in word documents through powershell.
By using a macro in normal.dot (all documents) and passing the find and replace text with the powershell script.

Macro

```vb
Sub Machine()

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = $Text
        .Replacement.Text = $ReplaceText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Powershell script

```bsh
$Desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$Document = "$Desktop\HL2532-00E.docx"

$Text = "2532-00"
$ReplaceText = "2532-35"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open("$Document")
$Word.Run("Machine")
$Document.Save()
$Word.Quit()
$a=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
```

Comment: Don't forget to ask your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not define any variables in your macro. You'll have to update it to something like this:

```
Sub Machine(FindText,ReplaceText)

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = FindText
        .Replacement.Text = ReplaceText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

Then when you call it from PowerShell you just add those arguments on after the name of the macro:

```
$Word.Run("Machine",$Text,$ReplaceText)
```

Or you can skip the macro and just do it all within PowerShell using the `Find.Execute()` method (documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.find.execute?view=word-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Word_Find_Execute_System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__System_Object__)).

```
$Document = "$home\Desktop\HL2532-00E.docx"

$Text = "2532-00"
$ReplaceText = "2532-35"

$Word = new-object -ComObject Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Open($Document)
$Find = $Document.Content.Find
$Find.ClearFormatting()|out-null
$Find.Execute($Text, $false, $false, $false, $false, $false, $true, 1, $false, $ReplaceText, 2)
$Document.Save()
$Word.Quit()
$a=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Word)
```

The syntax for the `Execute` method is this:

```
Execute(FindText, MatchCase, MatchWholeWord, MatchWildcards, MatchSoundsLike, MatchAllWordForms, Forward, Wrap, Format, ReplaceWith, Replace)
```

Most of those are `$true`/`$false`, with the `FindText` and `ReplaceWith` being strings. The two odd ones are `Wrap` and `Replace` that are enums where 1 = wdFindContinue and 2 = wdReplaceAll. You can find links to those enums on the page linked above.